# How can I calculate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {e^n(2n)!}{(4n)^nn!}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, analysis, limits

How should I get the result $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {e^n(2n)!}{(4n)^nn!}=\sqrt2$$
**without** relying on Stirling's formula or the Central Limit Theorem?

I am totally clueless. Can somebody help me?

Comment: I think you would have to do the equivalent of proving Stirling to get the result. Let me put it this way: if you're not to use Stirling or CLT, what are you allowed to use?

Comment: Unfortunately, the only way of analysing the factorial asymptotically is to use Stirling's formula or CLT. You will definitely be clueless in this case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is based on the following lemma.

> **Lemma**: If $f\in C^{1}[0,1] $ then $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)-n\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx=\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{2}$$
>   ([proof available here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/181819/72031))

In the above lemma it is [sufficient to assume the Riemann integrability of $f'$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/149174/72031).

If $a_n$ is the sequence in question and $L$ is the desired limit then we have
\begin{align} 
\log L&=\log \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\notag\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty} \log a_n\notag \\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} n\log\left(\frac{e}{4}\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)\notag\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)-n\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx\notag
\end{align}
where $f(x) =\log(1+x)$. Using the lemma we see that $$\log L=\frac{\log 2}{2}$$ and hence $L=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I loved this. $$$$

Comment: Is it $f'$ or $f$ that needs to be Riemann integrable?

Comment: @BarryCipra: well I established the result on this assumption of integrability of derivative. I think a simpler proof is possible with just integrability of $f$ and the limit can be expressed as $(f(1)-f(0))/2$.

Comment: @BarryCipra: added link to the proof of lemma.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, many thanks. It's a lovely lemma.

Comment: how come in the link the LHS of the lemma is -1 times what you have?

Comment: @BaroqueFreak: because the sum index in the link goes from $k=0$ to $n-1$. Changing this to $k=1$ to $k=n$ changes the sign and you can easily do the calculations for that. The second link deals with the same formula as used here.

Comment: What a beautiful idea! I truly appreciate your solution.

Answer (score -6):

## Solution

According to Stirling's formula, $$n!=\sqrt{2\pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \cdot e^{\frac{\theta}{12n}}~~,(0<\theta<1)$$

Hence, $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {e^n(2n)!}{(4n)^nn!}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{e^n\sqrt{4\pi n} \left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n} \cdot e^{\frac{\theta_1}{24n}}}{(4n)^n \sqrt{2\pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \cdot e^{\frac{\theta_2}{12n}}}=\sqrt{2}.$$

Comment: He DOES NOT WANT to use Stirling Formula.

Comment: I know his intention. But I think there exists no better solution for this without Stirling's formula, unless we are not afraid of the complexity.