# Evaluate $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \frac{((2n)!)^2}{2^{4n}(n!)^4}$

Tags: limits, factorial

$$\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \frac{((2n)!)^2}{2^{4n}(n!)^4}=0$$

How can I show this limit converges to 0?

I tried to use Sandwich Theorem, but I can't find proper fuction.

Comment: Stirling's formula?

Comment: This is the probability that you toss a fair coin $2n$ times and exactly half are heads, and then you try again and it happens again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you [know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation):

$$\text{n}!\sim\sqrt{2\pi\text{n}}\left(\frac{\text{n}}{e}\right)^\text{n}\tag1$$

So:

$$\frac{\left(\sqrt{2\pi\left(2\text{n}\right)}\left(\frac{2\text{n}}{e}\right)^{2\text{n}}\right)^2}{2^{4\text{n}}\left(\sqrt{2\pi\text{n}}\left(\frac{\text{n}}{e}\right)^\text{n}\right)^4}=\frac{1}{\text{n}\pi}\tag2$$

Comment: Numerator should be 2n/e (not n/e)...

Comment: @ION True! Thanks

Comment: It is kind of strange to use `\text{n}` in there.  Normally in mathematics we set a single-letter variable name in italics.  I'm guessing your Latex was generated by some program.  Europeans tend to write $e$ as $\text{e}$ because it is a constant, not a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Comment:
$$
\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }
{\frac { \left(  \left( 2\,n \right) ! \right) ^{
2}{x}^{2\,n}}{ \left( n! \right) ^{4}}}
=\;{}_2F_1\left(\frac12,\frac12;1;16x^2\right)
=\frac{2}{\pi}K\left( 4\,x \right)
$$
where $K$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind.  If we happen to know that $K(z)$ has a logarithmic singularity at $z=1$, then we can conclude that your sequence goes to $0$.  We could also get this from knowledge of the singularity of ${}_2F_1(\frac12,\frac12;1;z)$ at $z=1$.  Gauss already did the asymptotics of ${}_2F_1$ at its nearest singularity.

---

Here is a result of Gauss.  Study of the hypergeometric differential
equation shows that ${}_2F_1\left(a,b;c;z\right)$ is holomorphic on the open unit disk, and (unless the series terminates) has a singularity
at $z=1$ but no other singularity in the closed unit disk.

Theorem 2.1.3 in

> *Andrews, George E.; Askey, Richard; Roy, Ranjan*, Special functions, Encyclopedia of Mathematics and Its Applications. 71. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. xvi, 664 p. (1999). [ZBL0920.33001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0920.33001).

$$
{}_2F_1\left(a,b;a+b;z\right) \sim 
\frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}\;\log\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)
\quad\text{as }z \to 1^- .
\\\text{so}\\
{}_2F_1\left(\frac12,\frac12;1;z\right) \sim 
\frac{1}{\pi}\;\log\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)
\quad\text{as }z \to 1^- .
$$
But at $z=0$ we have the Maclaurin series
$$
\log\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\;z^n
\\ \text{so}\\
\frac{1}{\pi}\log\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\pi n}\;z^n
$$

Next there is  Darboux's formula.  It lets us
 recover the asymptotic properties of the Maclaurin coefficients of a series from knowledge of the nearest singularity of the function in the complex plane.
Theorem 8.4 in

> Gábor Szegö, *Orthogonal Polynomials*, American Mathematical Society, Colloquium Publications, Vol. XXIII. American Mathematical Society, Providence, R.I.

The result is that the Maclaurin coefficients
$$
a_n := {\frac { \left(  \left( 2\,n \right) ! \right) ^{
2}}{ 16^n\;\left( n! \right) ^{4}}}
$$
of ${}_2F_1\left(\frac12,\frac12;1;z\right)$ satisfy
$$
a_n \sim \frac{1}{\pi n} \quad\text{as } n \to \infty .
$$

Comment: It's quite difficult to understand. Thanks.

Comment: I was familiar with the Gauss asymptotic, but Darboux formula is cool. Thanks and +1

Answer (score 0):

Using [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2847768/72031) we have $$b_n=\frac{e^{2n}((2n)!)^2}{2^{4n}n^{2n}(n!)^2} \to 2$$ If $a_n$ is the sequence in question then we have $$\frac{a_n} {b_n} =\left(\frac{n^n} {e^n(n!)}\right)^2$$ and we can prove that $c_n=n^{n} /e^{n} n! \to 0$.

Let's observe that we have $$n\log\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}\to-\frac{1}{2}$$ (prove this using Taylor or LHospital). Hence there is a positive integer $m$ such that $$\log\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}<-\frac{1}{3n}$$ for all $n\geq m$. Adding such equations for all values of $n=m, m+1,\dots,N-1$ we get $$\log\frac{c_N}{c_m}<-\frac {1}{3}\sum_{n=m}^{N-1}\frac{1}{n}$$ The right hand side tends to $-\infty $ and therefore so does the left hand side as $N\to\infty $. It follows that $c_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty $. Thus the desired limit in question is $0$.

---

It turns out that the technique used for $c_n$ can be used directly for $a_n$. We have $$\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(2n+1)^2} {(2n+2)^2}\to 1$$ and hence $$n\log\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=n\cdot\frac{\log(a_{n+1}/a_n)}{(a_{n+1}/a_n)-1}\cdot\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1\right)\to - 1$$ and we can proceed in the same manner and show that $a_n\to 0$.

More generally this shows that *if $n\left(\left|\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right|-1\right)$ tends to a negative number then the sequence $x_n\to 0$*. If this limit is less than $-1$ then the series $\sum x_n$ is absolutely convergent (see [Raabe's test](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RaabesTest.html)).