# Help with $ \lim \frac{n\pi}{4} - \left( \frac{n^2}{n^2+1^2} +\frac{n^2}{n^2+2^2} + \cdots + \frac{n^2}{n^2+n^2} \right) $

Tags: real-analysis, limits, riemann-sum

I have proved that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left( \frac{n}{n^2+1^2} +\frac{n}{n^2+2^2} + \cdots + \frac{n}{n^2+n^2}  \right)  = \frac{\pi}{4},$$
by using the Riemann's sum of $\arctan$ on $[0,1]$. Now I'm interested in computing the next limit
$$ L=\lim_{n\to \infty} \left[ \frac{n\pi}{4} - \left( \frac{n^2}{n^2+1^2} +\frac{n^2}{n^2+2^2} + \cdots + \frac{n^2}{n^2+n^2}  \right) \right] $$
Note that
$$ L= \lim n  \left[ \frac{\pi}{4} - \left( \frac{n}{n^2+1^2} +\frac{n}{n^2+2^2} + \cdots + \frac{n}{n^2+n^2}  \right) \right] =[\infty \cdot 0].$$
I can't manage to calculate $L$. **How can this indeterminate form be solved?** Also, by using computer, I suspect that $L$ exists and is equal to $1/4$. Any idea or hint is welcome! (Actually, I dont need a complete solution, just a good start point). Have a nice day you all!

Comment: That idea is, more or less, what Gary shows in his solution, isn't it?

Comment: For any $f \in C^1([0,1])$ we have the general result $\lim_{n \to \infty} n\left(\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f(k/n) \right) = \frac{f(0) -f(1)}{2}$.  It is not generally true if $f$ is not continuously differentiable. See this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/615573/148510).

Comment: Thanks RRL for that reference! It's very interesting.

Comment: @RRL: that's a result which I have used often, for example [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2847768/72031). The answer has some links to other posts containing proofs of the result.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Yes -- it comes up here from time to time. It seems to hold under the weaker condition that $f'$ is integrable and Daniel Fischer proved it does not hold for all $f \in C([0,1])$.  What is an interesting exercise is to find a concrete example of a continuous function where it fails to hold.

Comment: @RRL: that's a nice idea for a new mathse question. I will try to think over it.

Answer (score 5):

By Taylor's formula
$$
\frac{1}{{1 + (x/n)^2 }} = \frac{1}{{1 + (k/n)^2 }} - \frac{1}{n}\frac{{2k/n}}{{(1 + (k/n)^2 )^2 }}(x - k) + \frac{{(3(\xi /n)^2  - 1)}}{{(1 + (\xi /n)^2 )^3 }}\frac{1}{{n^2 }}(x - k)^2 .
$$
for $0<x<n$, $0\leq k\leq n$ and some $0<\xi<n$ depending on $x$, $k$ and $n$. Since
$$
\left|\frac{{(3(\xi /n)^2  - 1)}}{{(1 + (\xi /n)^2 )^3}} \right|\leq 1
$$
for any $0<\xi<n$, we can write
$$
\frac{1}{{1 + (x/n)^2 }} = \frac{1}{{1 + (k/n)^2 }} - \frac{1}{n}\frac{{2k/n}}{{(1 + (k/n)^2 )^2 }}(x - k) + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{{n^2 }}\right)(x - k)^2
$$
uniformly for $0<x<n$ and $0\leq k\leq n$. Thus
$$
\int_{k - 1}^k {\frac{{dx}}{{1 + (x/n)^2 }}}  = \frac{1}{{1 + (k/n)^2 }} + \frac{1}{n}\frac{{k/n}}{{(1 + (k/n)^2 )^2 }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \right),
$$
and so
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{1 + (k/n)^2 }}}  = \frac{1}{n}\int_0^n {\frac{{dx}}{{1 + (x/n)^2 }}}  - \frac{1}{{n^2 }}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{k/n}}{{(1 + (k/n)^2 )^2 }}}  + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \right),
$$
i.e.,
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{n^2 }}{{n^2  + k^2 }}}  = \frac{\pi }{4}n - \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{k/n}}{{(1 + (k/n)^2 )^2 }}}  +\mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right).
$$
Finally,
$$
\frac{\pi }{4}n - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{n^2 }}{{n^2  + k^2 }}}  = \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{k/n}}{{(1 + (k/n)^2 )^2 }}}  + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right) \to \int_0^1 {\frac{x}{{(1 + x^2 )^2 }}dx}  = \frac{1}{4}.
$$

Comment: Woah... Taylor... I should have figured this out... Thanks for your solution +1!

Comment: This looks promising. However, the $\mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}}\right)$ depends on $n$ **but also on $k$**. You need to properly justify that this dependence doesn't influence the final result.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Thanks. Originally, I looked at the error term for all $0\leq k \leq n$ and found that it is uniformly $\mathcal{O}(n^{-2})$. I made the necessary changes.

Comment: @Gary Your new formula still depends **a priori** on $k$. You need I think to exhibit the next term of the Taylor series and bound in by something independent of $k$. This is not evident. At least for me.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net You can write the remainder explicitly as $$
\frac{{(3(\xi /n)^2  - 1)}}{{(1 + (\xi /n)^2 )^3 }}\frac{1}{{n^2 }}(x - k)^2 
$$ where $0<\xi<n$. The factor depending on $\xi$ is at most $1$.

Comment: @Gary This is convincing!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Thanks for your comments. I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x):=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ so$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}L_n,\,L_n:=n\int_0^1f(x)dx-\sum_{i=1}^nf(i/n).$$Taylor-expanding $f$,$$L_n=\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}c_{nk},\,c_{nk}:=n\int_0^1x^kdx-\frac{1}{n^k}\sum_{i=1}^ni^k\sim-\tfrac12$$by [Falhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula). So$$L=-\tfrac12\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}=-\tfrac12(f(1)-f(0))=\tfrac14.$$

Comment: Thanks for your solution, +1! Unfortunately, I was not familiar with Falhaber formula so I would never come up with your solution.

Comment: @Senna You could also use [Euler-Maclaurin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula).

Comment: What do you mean by Euler-Mclaurin?

Comment: @Senna I've added a link to my comment.