# Limit of harmonic series

Tags: limits

If $\lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(b-\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{n+r}\right)=a,$ find $a$ and $b.$

My progress:

As $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{n+r}=\ln 2\implies b=\ln 2$

Now what to do for $a$

Comment: Why does $b=\ln 2?$ You've shown that $a =\lim_{n\to\infty} n(b-\ln 2)$, but nothing more...

Comment: @RhysHughes: divide your equation by $n$ and you get $b=\log 2$.

Comment: @RhysHughes: if we admit that the existence of $a,b$ is implied in the question, then $\Sigma$ tends to $b$.

Comment: Nice question and yet a downvote! +1 already given to compensate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Getting the value of $a$ is tricky / non-obvious. Use the following lemma

> **Lemma**: If $f\in C^{1}[0,1] $ then $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)-n\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx=\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{2}$$
>   ([proof available here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/181819/72031))

In the above lemma it is [sufficient to assume the Riemann integrability of $f'$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/149174/72031).

For your question $f(x) = 1/(1+x)$ and the limit $a$ is $$\lim_{n\to\infty} n\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx-\sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(\frac{k} {n} \right)$$ which by above lemma equals $(f(0)-f(1))/2=1/4$.

Comment: I need to study that! Very nice, thanks!

Comment: @gimusi: in that case see an even more powerful application of this lemma at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2847768/72031

Answer (score 3):

Recall that by the [**rate of convergence**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Rate_of_divergence) of the Harmonic series

$$\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{n+r}=\sum_{r=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{r}-\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{r}= \ln 2n+\gamma+\frac1{4n}-\ln n-\gamma-\frac1{2n}+o\left(\frac1n\right)=$$$$=\ln 2-\frac1{4n}+o\left(\frac1n\right)$$

then we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(b-\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{n+r}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(b-\ln 2+\frac1{4n}+o\left(\frac1n\right)\right)=a$$

therefore $b=\ln 2$ and $a =\frac14$.

Comment: +1 already there, but you may replace $\sim$ with $=$ and add $o(1/n)$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes that's better as you suggested! Thanks