# Finding the limit of $n(\ln2-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k})$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $$A_n:=\frac{1}{n+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}.$$
It is well known that $A_n$ is an increasing sequence, and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}A_n=\ln(2)$.
Motivated by how fast $A_n$ converges to $ln(2)$, I would like to know the limit below
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\left(\ln(2)-A_n\right).$$

First, since $1/(1+x)$ is a strictly decreasing function, we have
$$\ln 2=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x}\, dx<\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{1+k/n}=\frac{1}{n}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n-1}.$$
Therefore, we have
$$\ln(2)-A_n<\left(\frac{1}{n}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n-1}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}\right)=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n}=\frac{1}{2n}.$$
Hence $B_n:=n(\ln2-A_n)$ is bounded from above, and
$$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}B_n\le \frac{1}{2}.$$

Furthermore, since $b_n:=1/(\ln 2-A_n)$ is strictly increasing, by the Stolz theorem, we have
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}B_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{b_{n+1}-b_n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}4(1+\frac{1}{2n})B_nB_{n+1}.$$

Therefore, if $B_n$ has a limit, then the limit has to be $0$ or $1/4$.

However, first, I have some trouble in showing the monotonicity of $B_n$, and more importantly, I don't know how to exclude the possibility that the limit of $B_n$ cannot be $0$.

Any ideas or comments are fully appreciated.

Comment: Another way is to use the asymptotic result $\sum_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{k}}  = \ln n + \gamma  + \frac{1}{{2n}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \right)$ which gives $n\left( {\ln 2 - \sum_{k = n + 1}^{2n} {\frac{1}{k}} } \right) = \frac{1}{4} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the limit of $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} n \, \left( \ln 2 - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n+k} \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \phi_{n} $$ in the following way.
Since $$H_{n} \approx \ln n + \gamma + \frac{1}{2 n} - \frac{1}{12 \, n^2} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) $$ then
\begin{align*}
\phi_{n} &= n \, \left( \ln 2 - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n+k} \right) \\
&= n \, \left( \ln 2 - (H_{2n} - H_{n}) \right) \\
&= n \, \left( \ln 2 - \left( \ln 2 - \frac{1}{4 n} + \frac{1}{16 \, n^2} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) \right) \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{16 \, n} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right).
\end{align*}

From this is it can be seen that
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} n \, \left( \ln 2 - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n+k} \right) = \frac{1}{4}. $$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

The result is pretty general:

> **Lemma**: If $f\in C^{1}[0,1] $ then $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)-n\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx=\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{2}$$
> ([proof available here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/181819/72031))

In the above lemma it is [sufficient to assume the Riemann integrability of $f'$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/149174/72031).

For your current problem $f(x) =1/(1+x)$ and then the lemma says that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k}-\log 2\right) =\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{2}$$ so that the desired limit is $1/4$.

Comment: Thanks so much for the very nice formula!

Comment: @QFL: there is an extension of the formula at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4562778/72031

Answer (score 4):

Another simple way without replying on properties of Harmonic functions (which are not very easy to prove) is to use the [Stolz-Cesaro Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem_for_the_0/0_case) which is an analogue of the L'Hospital Rule in the discrete case.

Write it as $$\frac{\ln(2)-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+k}}{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}$$ and we have a $\frac{0}{0}$ form.

You get using the Theorem above that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n}-a_{n+1}}{b_{n}-b_{n+1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{n+1+k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+k}}{\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}}$$

Which is just $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{ \frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}-\frac{1}{n+1}}{\frac{1}{n(n+1)}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n(n+1)}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}=\frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer. I did not realize there is a version of Stolz theorem for 0/0, but this is indeed correct.

Answer (score 3):

Notice $\log 2 = \log\frac{2n}{n} = \sum\limits_{m=n}^{2n-1}\log\frac{m+1}{m}$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\log 2 - \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k} 
& = \sum_{m=n}^{2n-1}\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{m+x} - \frac{1}{m+1}\right)dx\\
& = \sum_{m=n}^{2n-1}\int_0^1\frac{1-x}{(m+x)(m+1)}dx\\
& = \sum_{m=n}^{2n-1}\int_0^1\left(\frac{1-x}{m(m+1)} - \frac{x(1-x)}{m(m+1)(m+x)}\right)dx\\
&= \sum_{m=n}^{2n-1}\left[\frac12\left(\frac1m - \frac1{m+1}\right) - \int_0^1 \frac{x(1-x)}{m(m+1)(m+x)}dx\right]\\
&= \frac1{4n} - \sum_{m=n}^{2n-1}\int_0^1 \frac{x(1-x)}{m(m+1)(m+x)}dx
\end{align}
$$
This leads to the bound
$$\begin{align}
\left|n\left(\log 2 - \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k}\right) - \frac14\right|
& = n \sum_{m=n}^{2n-1} \int_0^1 \frac{x(1-x)}{m(m+1)(m+x)}dx\\
& \le \sum_{m=n}^{2n-1} \int_0^1 \frac{x(1-x)}{m(m+1)}dx\\
& = \frac{1}{12n}
\end{align}
$$
As a result,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(\log 2 - \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k}\right) = \frac14$$

Comment: Thanks! This is also a very good approach! For me, I like this approach more.