# Find a mistake in finding limit, please.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I wanted to find the limit: $\lim_{n \to +\infty}(\frac{1^p + 2^p + ... + n^p}{n^p} - \frac{n}{p + 1})$, where $p \in \mathbb{N}$.

I saw that I could use [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), where $x_n = (p + 1)(1^p + 2^p + ... + n^p) - n^{p + 1}$, and $y_n = n^p(p + 1)$ tends to +$\infty$.

So, here we are:

$\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { { x }_{ n }-{ x }_{ n - 1 } }{ { y }_{ n }-{ y }_{ n - 1 } } } = \lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { ( p+1 ) { n  }^{ p }-{n}^{ p+1 }+{ (n-1) }^{ p+1 } }{ ( p+1 ) ( { n }^{ p }-{ (n-1) }^{ p } )  } } = \lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { ( p+1 )-n+(n-1)(\frac{n - 1}{n})^p  }{ ( p+1 ) ( 1-{ (\frac{n-1}{n}) }^{ p } )  } } = \lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { p  }{ 0 } } $ (because $(\frac{n - 1}{n})^p$ tends to 1).

But as I understood [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149142/evaluating-lim-limits-n-to-infty-left-frac1p2p3p-cdots-npnp), limit of this sequence is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Where did I go wrong in my reasoning and why is my answer not correct?

Comment: According to the theorem, $x_n$ can be any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final identity
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty  }{ \frac { ( p+1 )-n+(n-1)(\frac{n - 1}{n})^p  }{ ( p+1 ) ( 1-{ (\frac{n-1}{n}) }^{ p } )  } } = \lim _{n\to \infty  }{ \frac { p  }{ 0 } }
$$
is wrong. It is correct that $(\frac{n - 1}{n})^p$ tends to one, but that does not imply that $1 - n + (n-1)(\frac{n - 1}{n})^p$ tends to zero and and can be ignored in the numerator. Also the denominator tends to $p+1$, not to zero.

For a correct solution using the Stolz–Cesàro theorem  see for example haqnatural's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1371368/42969).

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { ( p+1 ) { n  }^{ p }-{n}^{ p+1 }+{ (n-1) }^{ p+1 } }{ ( p+1 ) ( { n }^{ p }-{ (n-1) }^{ p } )  } } $$
set $n=\frac{1}{x}$ the limit becomes
$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0  }\frac{(p+1) \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^p-\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{p+1}+\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)^{p+1}}{(p+1) \left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^p-\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)^p\right)}$$
dramatic simplification
$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0  }\frac{\frac{p}{1-(1-x)^p}+1-\frac{1}{x}}{p+1}$$
MacLaurin expansion
$$\frac{\frac{p}{1-(1-x)^p}+1-\frac{1}{x}}{p+1}\sim \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{12} (p-1) x+O\left(x^2\right)$$
as $x\to 0$ we have $$\frac{\frac{p}{1-(1-x)^p}+1-\frac{1}{x}}{p+1}\to \frac{1}{2}$$