# Hidden property of the graph of $y=\tan{x}$: infinite product of lengths of zigzag line segments converges, but to what?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry, closed-form, infinite-product

On the graph of $y=\tan{x}$, $0<x<\pi/2$, draw $2n$ zigzag line segments that, with the *x*-axis, form equal-width isosceles triangles whose top vertices lie on the curve. Here is an example with $n=6$.

[image]

It seems that, as $n\to\infty$, the product of their lengths converges to a positive number. The limit is:

$$L=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\exp{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n}\ln{\left(\left(\frac{\pi}{4n}\right)^2+\tan^2{\left(\frac{2k-1}{4n}\pi\right)}\right)}$$

Desmos suggests that $L\approx 2.50917847$. I am looking for a closed form for this limit.

I've been trying to apply what I learned about sums of logs in a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4562078/show-that-lim-n-to-inftyn-leftn-lnn-ln-sqrt2-n-sum-k-1n-ln-lef) of mine, but I still have not been able to evaluate this one.

If we change the graph to $y=\tan{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)}$, $0<x<1$, the corresponding limit seems strikingly similar to $\frac{1}{2}\left(e+\frac{1}{e}\right)$, based on computer calculation. So, assuming that is the correct limit in that case, I would expect the limit in this question, $L$, to look something along those lines.

I find it interesting that a geometrical infinite product, that is neither $0$ nor $\infty$, exists in such a simple geometrical construction, without needing to make any modifications.

EDIT: Thanks to @Jean Marie's comment, I am very confident that $L=\cosh{(\pi/2)}$. But how to prove this?

Comment: Another way to write $\frac12(e+1/e)$ is $\cosh(1)$. I don't know it it helps...

Comment: @JeanMarie Oh my cosh, it's $\cosh{(\pi/2)}$. Thanks!

Comment: 1) No, $\frac12(e+1/e)$ isn't $\cosh(\pi/2)$... 2) Pun "oh my cosh" appreciated. In the same register : "God, forgive my sin"...

Comment: @JeanMarie I meant $L=\cosh{(\pi/2)}$.

Comment: At the risk of sounding *hyperbolic*, this is an earth-shattering result.

Comment: Maybe there is a Riemann sum hiding in there?

Comment: This would be interesting to prove. (+1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression under the limit **has a closed form**: by factoring $z^{2n}+1$, one gets $$P_n(a,b):=\prod_{k=1}^n\left(a^2-2ab\cos\frac{2k-1}{2n}\pi+b^2\right)=a^{2n}+b^{2n},$$ thus $$\prod_{k=1}^n\left(x^2+\tan^2\frac{2k-1}{4n}\pi\right)=\frac{P_n(1+x,1-x)}{P_n(1,-1)}=\frac12\big((1+x)^{2n}+(1-x)^{2n}\big).$$ Now plug in $x=\pi/(4n)$ and take $n\to\infty$ to get $L=\cosh(\pi/2)$.

Comment: Thanks (again)! In general, when trying to evaluate an infinite product, I'm not sure when it's easier to evaluate it as a sum of logs, and when to evaluate it directly as a product (as you have done here). I guess both approaches are feasible, but sometimes one is easier than the other?

Comment: @Dan: Well, the direct way *looks* easy *when possible* (a rare beast...).